# Python ssl problem with multiprocessing

Tags: python, ssl, multiprocessing

I want to send data from a client to the server in a TLS TCP socket from multiple client subprocesses so I share the same ssl socket with all subprocesses. Communication works with one subprocess, but if I use more than one subprocesses, the TLS server crashes with an `ssl.SSLError` (SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac).

**More specific:** It does not depend which process first calls the `SSLSocket.write()` method, but this process is the only one from this time on which can call it. If another process calls `write()`, the server will result in the exception described above.

I used this basic code:

**tlsserver.py**

```
import socket, ssl

def deal_with_client(connstream):
    data = connstream.read()
    while data:
        print data
        data = connstream.read()
    connstream.close()

bindsocket = socket.socket()
bindsocket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 9998))
bindsocket.listen(5)

while True:
    newsocket, fromaddr = bindsocket.accept()
    connstream = ssl.wrap_socket(newsocket,
                                server_side=True,
                                certfile="srv.crt",
                                keyfile="srv.key",
                                ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
    deal_with_client(connstream)
```

**tlsclient.py**

```
import socket, ssl
import multiprocessing

class SubProc:
    def __init__(self, sock):
        self.sock = sock

    def do(self):
        self.sock.write("Test")

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s)
ssl_sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 9998))

print "Connected to", repr(ssl_sock.getpeername())

for x in (1,2):
    subproc = SubProc(ssl_sock)
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=subproc.do)
```

And this is the backtrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tlsserver.py", line 21, in <module>
    deal_with_client(connstream)
  File "tlsserver.py", line 7, in deal_with_client
    data = connstream.read()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/ssl.py", line 136, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:1325: error:1408F119:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The problem is that you're re-using the same connection for both processes. The way SSL encrypts data makes this fail -- the two processes would have to communicate with each other about the state of the shared SSL connection. Even if you do make it work, or if you didn't use SSL, the data would arrive at the server all jumbled up; you would have no real way of distinguishing which bytes came from which process.

What you need to do is give each process its own SSL connection, by making the connection in `subproc.do`. Alternatively, don't have the subprocesses communicate with the server at all, but rather communicate with the main process, and have the main process relay it over the SSL connection.

Comment: Thank's for information! I was afraid this would be the problem. I think i will for a process which only does ssl communication and all other processes will communicate with this one via pipes. Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: Would you be so kind and can you explain why even a lock does not solve this problem?

Comment: I was having similar issues with using SSL and multiprocessing.Process.  I found that switching to using multithreading.Thread sufficiently worked around this problem.  I can't find exactly what I read that led me to go down this path, but I believe that it is because of the way that the openssl library is using the process information to do something with the en/decryption on the raw socket.  And when that socket is created on one process and then passed to another process, something goes wrong.  Creating in one thread and passing to another thread seems to be just fine 

Comment: @danielpops do you have some working snippet? I am trying to scrape an SSL based site with multiprocessing and got the error