# Python requests ssl [Errno 1] _ssl.c:1428: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I'm creating a python app, using requests module. I recently add multiprocessing to speed it up a bit, but I started to get some strange errors like `[Errno 1] _ssl.c:1428: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number` or `[Errno 1] _ssl.c:1428: error:1408F119:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac`.
The code looks like this:

```
def hometables_one(conn, request, s, hostname, payload, company):
    date1 = request.query.get('date1', '')      
    date2 = request.query.get('date2', '')

    prijmyCelk = 0;
    vydajeCelk = 0;
    neuhrPrijCelk = 0;
    neuhrVydCelk = 0;
    dph = 0;
    dbNazev = company['dbNazev'];
    nazev = company['nazev'];

    if date1 and date2:
        try:
            r = s.get("%s/c/%s/faktura-vydana/(duzpPuv between %s %s)/$sum.json" % (hostname, dbNazev, date1[0], date2[0]), params=payload, verify=False)
            r.raise_for_status()
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
            #response.write(ujson.dumps({ "success": False, "errors": { "reason": str(err)}}))
            #return response
            conn.send({ "success": False, "errors": { "reason": str(err)}})
            conn.close()
            return None

    else:
        try:
            r = s.get("%s/c/%s/faktura-vydana/$sum.json" % (hostname, dbNazev), params=payload, verify=False)
            r.raise_for_status()
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
            #response.write(ujson.dumps({ "success": False, "errors": { "reason": str(err)}}))
            #return response
            conn.send({ "success": False, "errors": { "reason": str(err)}})
            conn.close()
            return None

    obj_vydana = r.json()
    data_vydana = obj_vydana['winstrom']['sum']['sumDoklUcetni']['values']
    prijmyCelk = float(data_vydana['sumDoklCelkem']['value'])
    neuhrVydCelk = float(data_vydana['sumDoklZbyvaUh']['value'])
    dph_vydane = float(data_vydana['sumDoklDphCelk']['value'])


    if date1 and date2:
        try:
            r = s.get("%s/c/%s/faktura-prijata/(duzpPuv between %s %s)/$sum.json" % (hostname, dbNazev, date1[0], date2[0]), params=payload, verify=False)
            r.raise_for_status()
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
            #response.write(ujson.dumps({ "success": False, "errors": { "reason": str(err)}}))
            #return response
            conn.send({ "success": False, "errors": { "reason": str(err)}})
            conn.close()
            return None

    else:
        try:
            r = s.get("%s/c/%s/faktura-prijata/$sum.json" % (hostname, dbNazev), params=payload, verify=False)
            r.raise_for_status()
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
            #response.write(ujson.dumps({ "success": False, "errors": { "reason": str(err)}}))
            #return response
            conn.send({ "success": False, "errors": { "reason": str(err)}})
            conn.close()
            return None

    obj_prijata = r.json();
    data_prijata = obj_prijata['winstrom']['sum']['sumDoklUcetni']['values']
    vydajeCelk = float(data_prijata['sumDoklCelkem']['value'])
    neuhrPrijCelk = float(data_prijata['sumDoklZbyvaUh']['value'])
    dph_prijate = float(data_prijata['sumDoklDphCelk']['value'])

    if prijmyCelk != 0:
        result = {
            "corporation": nazev,
            "dbName": dbNazev,
            "prijmyCelk": "%s €" % prijmyCelk,
            "nakladyCelk": "%s €" % vydajeCelk,
            "ziskCelk": "%s €" % (prijmyCelk-vydajeCelk),
            "marzaCelk": ((prijmyCelk-vydajeCelk)/prijmyCelk*100),
            "neuhrVydCelk": "%s €" % neuhrVydCelk,
            "neuhrPrijCelk": "%s €" % neuhrPrijCelk,
            "dph": "%s €" % (dph_vydane-dph_prijate),
        }
    else:
        result = {
            "corporation": nazev,
            "dbName": dbNazev,
            "prijmyCelk": "%s €" % prijmyCelk,
            "nakladyCelk": "%s €" % vydajeCelk,
            "ziskCelk": "%s €" % (prijmyCelk-vydajeCelk),
            "marzaCelk": 0,
            "neuhrVydCelk": "%s €" % neuhrVydCelk,
            "neuhrPrijCelk": "%s €" % neuhrPrijCelk,
            "dph": "%s €" % (dph_vydane-dph_prijate),
        }
    conn.send(result)
    conn.close()
    return None
#####################################################################################

def hometables(request):
    s = requests.Session()
    response = HTTPResponse()
    hostname = request.query.get('hostname', '')[0]
    auth = request.query.get('auth', '')[0]
    p_queue = []
    result = []

    json_r = {"success": True}
    payload = {'authSessionId': request.query.get('auth', '')[0]}
    try:
        r = s.get("%s/c.json" % hostname, params=payload, verify=False)
        r.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        response.write(ujson.dumps({ "success": False, "errors": { "reason": str(err)}}))
        return response

    obj = r.json()
    data = obj['companies']['company']
    data = make_list(data)

    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    for company in data:
        p_queue.append(Process(target=hometables_one, args=(child_conn, request, s, hostname, payload, company))) #create a new process with hometables_one function
        p_queue[-1].start()

    for p in p_queue:
        received_data = parent_conn.recv()
        if "success" not in received_data:
            result.append(received_data)s
            p.join()
        else:
            response.write(ujson.dumps(received_data)) #error in hometables_one function
            return response

    json_r["data"] = result
    response.write(ujson.dumps(json_r))
    return response
```

In this part

```
    try:
        r = s.get("%s/c.json" % hostname, params=payload, verify=False)
        r.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        response.write(ujson.dumps({ "success": False, "errors": { "reason": str(err)}}))
        return response

    obj = r.json()
    data = obj['companies']['company']
            data = make_list(data)
```

I get a JSON request with all companies currently in system and then I run the hometables_one function for each of them. The final `data` may look like this:

```
[{"createDt":"2014-01-28T00:00:00+01:00","dbNazev":"sveatlo","id":"4","licenseGroup":"null","nazev":"Sveatlo","show":"true","stavEnum":"ESTABLISHED","watchingChanges":"false"}]
```

or like this:

```
[{"createDt":"2014-01-28T00:00:00+01:00","dbNazev":"sveatlo","id":"4","licenseGroup":"null","nazev":"Sveatlo","show":"true","stavEnum":"ESTABLISHED","watchingChanges":"false"},{"createDt":"2014-01-28T00:00:00+01:00","dbNazev":"sveatlo1","id":"4","licenseGroup":"null","nazev":"Sveatlo1","show":"true","stavEnum":"ESTABLISHED","watchingChanges":"false"}]
```

In the first case, when there is just one item the `hometables_one` function runs without any problems, but adding another item results in error `[Errno 1] _ssl.c:1428: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number` or `[Errno 1] _ssl.c:1428: error:1408F119:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac`. Another thing is that when I run the code without multiprocessing, i.e. content of hometable_one function is in the for loop in hometables function, it runs without any problems.
Why am I getting these errors? Could anybody help me please?

Thanks for any answer

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724900/python-ssl-problem-with-multiprocessing

Comment: Could be related to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783735/problem-with-multi-threaded-python-app-and-socket-connections - if so, some solutions at that link.

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced similar problems. I think this error is the result of multiple processes trying to access the same SSL connection. What you can try is to introduce a random delay for each process before they fire off the request:

```
time.sleep(random.randrange(10))
r = s.get("%s/c.json" % hostname, params=payload, verify=False)
```

Comment: I had the similar error when I tried to install [airflow](https://github.com/airbnb/airflow). I modified the below file as you advised. Then it worked well, thank you. /usr/local/src/Python-2.7.5/Lib/ssl.py