# optimize loop making django-rest-framework requests

Tags: django-rest-framework, python-multiprocessing

I have a for loop that iterates over an array. For each item in the array, it calls a function that makes django-rest-framework requests. Each function call is independent of the others.

If the array has 25 items, it currently takes 30 seconds to complete. I am trying to get the total time down to less than 10 seconds.

Half the time spent in the function is taken up by DRF requests. Would it make sense to replace the for loop with a multiprocessing Pool? If so, how do I to ensure each process makes requests over a separate connection using the requests package?

I tried just replacing:

> ```
> for scenario_id in scenario_ids:
>     step_scenario_partial(scenario_id)
> ```

with:

> ```
> pool = Pool(processes=2)
> pool.map(step_scenario_partial, scenario_ids)
> ```

which failed due to OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_record', 'decryption failed or bad record mac')]

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724900/python-ssl-problem-with-multiprocessing), the error was due to re-using the same SSL connection in more than one process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `concurrent` python module ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)) which can execute parallel tasks. Example method that returns a list of response objects:

```
from concurrent import futures

def execute_all(scenario_ids, num_workers=5):
    '''
    Method to make parallel API calls
    '''
    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_workers) as executor:
        return [result for result in executor.map(step_scenario_partial, scenario_ids)]
```

The `ThreadPoolExecutor` uses a pool of threads to execute asynchronous parallel calls. You can experiment with values of num_workers, starting with 5, to ensure the total execution time is <10 seconds.

Comment: Will threads avoid errors due to re-using the same SSL connection because the threads never execute concurrently?

Comment: Tried out your suggestion. The cumtime  went down to 8.3 seconds without errors.